# Rotate ellipsoid in Tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

This is the result of my code: [image: result]
Now, I would like to have the inner ellipsoid aligned with the x-axis, and not with the y-axis as it is. In other words, I would like to rotate the all ellipsoid in the xy-plane by 90 degrees, so I should introduce some prospective somehow, like this (in black where I want to place the ellipsoid):[image]
How should I modify my code? (Simplified code without axis and lines, but that's not important)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.3][line cap=round, line join=round]
    \draw [ball color=white,very thin,opacity=0.4] (0,0,0) circle (8) ;
    \fill[white,opacity=0.6] (0,0) circle (8 and 3);
    \shade[right color=orange,middle color=red,left color=blue,opacity=0.4,shading angle=-110] (0,0) circle (8 and 3);
    \shade[ball color=orange,opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle (8 and 3);
    \draw[line width=0.5pt,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},dash pattern=on 4pt off 3pt, color = violet, opacity = 0.6] (0,0) ellipse (1 and 3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Do you have analytic expressions of the ellipsoid and the sphere (radius, major and minor axes) ? or you just want a similar like the one you posted?

Comment: @BlackMild Just a similar one, it should only give an intuitive view of what is happening.

Comment: "the inner ellipsoid aligned with the x-axis, and not with the y-axis as it is. In other words, I would like to rotate the all ellipsoid in the xy-plane by 90 degrees" <<< this description is unclear. Please improve it!

Comment: @BlackMild It should be clear enough now

Answer (score 2):

You are using a 2D tool to create a 3D figure, so it will never be perfect. Here I have just guessed some numbers.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
\shadedraw[ball color=white, fill opacity=0.8] (0,0,0) circle[radius=8];
\shadedraw[ball color=white, fill opacity=0.8, shading angle=-45, rotate=45] (0,0,0) ellipse[x radius=4.3, y radius=3];
\shadedraw[left color=blue, right color=orange, fill opacity=0.4, shading angle=-45, rotate=45] (0,0,0) ellipse[x radius=4.3, y radius=3];
\draw[dashed, rotate=45] (0,0,0) ellipse[x radius=4.3/3, y radius=3];
\draw[-Latex]  (0,0,0) -- (8,0,0);
\draw[-Latex]  (0,0,0) -- (0,8,0);
\draw[-Latex]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shaded ball and elipsoid]

Comment: Maybe @Black Mild will post a real 3D asymptote version. -or maybe you like to tinker with the 2D version until it looks passable.

Comment: Oh, I have just posted a 3D Asymptote ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better code of 3D figure with Asymptote, but for now, here is one solution. `rotate(45,X)` is the rotation of `45` degrees around the x-axis `O--X`.

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
// code modified from https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/c0185797a0/
import graph3;
import smoothcontour3;
unitsize(1cm);
currentprojection.zoom=.8;
real a=2.5, b=3, c=1;
real f(real x, real y, real z) {return x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1;}
draw(rotate(45,X)*implicitsurface(f,(-a,-b,-c),(a,b,c),maxdepth=7),pink+opacity(.5));
draw(scale3(b)*unitsphere,yellow+opacity(.2));

xlimits(-a,b+1);
ylimits(-b,b+1);
zlimits(-c,b+1);
axes3("$x$","$y$","$z$",Arrow3);
```

I am trying the following simpler code, but I can not debug it.

```
unitsize(3cm);
import graph3;
transform3 t=rotate(45,X)*scale(0.8,1,0.5);
draw(t*unitsphere,purple+opacity(.3));
draw(unitsphere,yellow+opacity(.2));

axes3("$x$","$y$","$z$",Arrow3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

With your simplified code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.3][line cap=round, line join=round]
        \draw [ball color=white,very thin,opacity=0.4] (0,0,0) circle (8) ;
        \node [right] at (8,0) {$y$};
        \node [above] at (0,8) {$z$};
        \node [above] at (-2.2,-4) {$x$};
        %\draw[line width=0.5pt,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},dash pattern=on 7pt off 8pt] (0,0) ellipse (8 and 2);
        \draw[line width=1pt,-latex]  (0,0) -- (0,8);
        \draw[line width=1pt,-latex]  (0,0) -- (-2,-3);
        \draw[line width=1pt,-latex]  (0,0) -- (8,0);
        \fill[white,opacity=0.6] (0,0) circle (8 and 3);
        \shade[right color=orange,middle color=red,left color=blue,opacity=0.4,shading angle=-110] (0,0) circle (8 and 3);
        \shade[ball color=orange,opacity=0.3] (0,0) circle (8 and 3);
    %   \draw[line width=0.5pt,rotate around={0.:(90.,0.)},dash pattern=on 4pt off 3pt, color = violet, opacity = 0.6] (0,0) ellipse (1 and 3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I honestly don't see any difference. I would like the ellipsoid to be alligned with the x axis